# MySQL: Filter rows based on a relationship table

Tags: mysql

I'm a bit lost on this one, I have a problem displaying rows on a table based on values of its relationship table. I'm not sure how to go about this. My expected results are as follows:

**Expected Results**

```
-- Expected Result #1: (user_id = 1 only, applied)
------  --------  -------  --------
    id  position  user_id  meta_key
------  --------  -------  --------
     1  Waiter          1  applied 
     2  Busboy     (NULL)  (NULL)  
     3  Driver     (NULL)  (NULL)  
     4  Chef            1  applied 
------  --------  -------  --------

-- Expected Result #2: Same as above except filtered by category IN(98)
------  --------  -------  --------
    id  position  user_id  meta_key
------  --------  -------  --------
     1  Waiter          1  applied    (uses category: 98, 99)
     2  Busboy     (NULL)  (NULL)     (uses category: 98)
     3  Driver     (NULL)  (NULL)     (uses category: 98)
------  --------  -------  --------
```

**My tables**

```
Table 1: Position
------  --------  ---------
    id  position  user_id  
------  --------  ---------
     1  Waiter            1
     2  Busboy            1
     3  Driver            2
     4  Chef              3
------  --------  ---------

Table 2: Meta
------  -------  -----------  --------  ------------
    id  user_id  position_id  meta_key  meta_value  
------  -------  -----------  --------  ------------
     1        1            1  category  98          
     2        1            1  category  99          
     3        1            2  category  98          
     4        2            3  category  98          
     5        3            4  category  100          
     7        1            1  applied   1
     8        2            1  applied   1
     9        3            1  applied   1
    10        1            4  applied   1
------  -------  -----------  --------  ------------
```

In my expected results, all positions are being displayed except when it is being filtered by a single category or categories. Users basically "apply" to positions and their user_id is shown if they applied to it. But if the entry is from a position they didn't apply to, the position is still shown but with a `user_id` field of `NULL`.

Is it possible for MySQL to do something like this? My initial query was able to accomplish the first expected result but not the second where it is filtered by category.

**My query (user_id = 1)**

```
SELECT pos.id, pos.position, meta.user_id, meta.meta_key
 FROM `position` pos
    LEFT JOIN meta ON pos.id = meta.position_id 
                  AND meta.meta_key = 'applied' 
                  AND meta.user_id = 1
```

**SQL file**

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `position`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `position` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `position` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `position` VARCHAR(191) NULL,
  `user_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `meta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `meta` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `meta` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT NULL,
  `position_id` INT NULL,
  `meta_key` VARCHAR(191) NULL,
  `meta_value` VARCHAR(191) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `position`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `position` (`id`, `position`, `user_id`) VALUES (1, 'Waiter', 1);
INSERT INTO `position` (`id`, `position`, `user_id`) VALUES (2, 'Busboy', 1);
INSERT INTO `position` (`id`, `position`, `user_id`) VALUES (3, 'Driver', 2);
INSERT INTO `position` (`id`, `position`, `user_id`) VALUES (4, 'Chef', 3);

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `meta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `meta` (`id`, `user_id`, `position_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'category', '98');
INSERT INTO `meta` (`id`, `user_id`, `position_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (2, 1, 1, 'category', '99');
INSERT INTO `meta` (`id`, `user_id`, `position_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (3, 1, 2, 'category', '98');
INSERT INTO `meta` (`id`, `user_id`, `position_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (4, 2, 3, 'category', '98');
INSERT INTO `meta` (`id`, `user_id`, `position_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (5, 3, 4, 'category', '100');
INSERT INTO `meta` (`id`, `user_id`, `position_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (7, 1, 1, 'applied', '1');
INSERT INTO `meta` (`id`, `user_id`, `position_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (8, 2, 1, 'applied', '1');
INSERT INTO `meta` (`id`, `user_id`, `position_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (9, 3, 1, 'applied', '1');
INSERT INTO `meta` (`id`, `user_id`, `position_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (10, 1, 4, 'applied', '1');

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Can you give us the sample data as ddl?

Comment: What do you mean by ddl?

Comment: He meant this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a546f

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want but I'm trying anyway

Comment: What are the relationship between those tables ?

Comment: Added the SQL creation file.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't update my post after updating the schema. I updated the meta table and reposted the DDL to ensure there are no discrepancies.

Comment: I don't understand your expected result, why should busboy have two null fields in the result?

Comment: The result you desired is currently impossible for the data you provided. Best you will have is this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a546f/32 with the given data, So check it and if it is the real result let me know and I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not it. I can see where you're coming from. Would there be a better way to do this with a different schema? Basically, there are many positions which users apply to and you can view these positions by their category.

Comment: What you mean by a different schema?

Answer (score 0):

To show Expected Results #2 is possible, one way to do it is creating a view, and filtering by category.

These are the commands I executed.

MariaDB [test]> create view v as SELECT pos.id, pos.position, meta.user_id, meta.meta_key FROM `position` pos LEFT JOIN meta ON pos.id = meta.position_id AND meta.meta_key = 'applied' AND meta.user_id = 1;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from v where id in (select position_id from meta where meta_key='category' and meta_value='98');

+----+----------+---------+----------+
| id | position | user_id | meta_key |
+----+----------+---------+----------+
|  1 | Waiter   |       1 | applied  |
|  2 | Busboy   |    NULL | NULL     |
|  3 | Driver   |    NULL | NULL     |
+----+----------+---------+----------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)